# Java - Converting copyright symbol to &copy;

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a string coming in, which I need to store in the db. Now the string does contain the copyright symbol ©. I want to convert this to &copy ; so that it can be displayed properly on each and every browser and with every encoding standard.

This is where I've reached up until now 
- tried replace(), which definitely wouldn't have worked anyways for the copyright character.
- tried turning tables by setting different encoding standards to view data in the browser, it gets displayed as a � 
- converted the string to a byte array with UTF-8 charset and figured out that -62 is that ASCII value for the copyright character. Now the problem is that the string coming in could be quite big and splitting it up to a byte array and then forming a string back would be very expensive.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why didn't `replace()` work?  What result did you get when you tried it?

Comment: There is no ASCII value of the copyright character, because ASCII doesn't contain it!

Comment: ok.. now somethings have started working - for the most part. The problem is now with displaying the copyright character. Using FIREBUG, I see that the response that my server generates for the request does contain the Copyright character. Its just not being displayed that way; head does contain charset as utf-8!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## HTML-Escaping

This may not solve your encoding issues but answering your question from title.

To HTML-escape a String I recommend `StringEscapeUtils` from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(String)
```

---

## Encoding

To address your encoding problems..when you want to use `UTF-8` then ensure that at least one of the following things is set. Additionally when setting more than one of them then all of them have to be consistent.

### Content-Type in HTTP-Header

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

### HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

### HTML 5

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

### XHTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Also ensure that the content you're serving is really UTF-8 encoded. I recommend to use UTF-8 encoding without BOM.

Comment: ok.. now somethings have started working - for the most part. The problem is now with displaying the copyright character. Using FIREBUG, I see that the response that my server generates for the request does contain the Copyright character. Its just not being displayed that way; head does contain charset as utf-8!

Comment: escapeHtml messes up all the tags, spaces, everything. I just want to change the copyright symbol. str.replace("\u00a9", "&copy;") just doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Then only pass the copyright symbol through that method. But it is a bit wired to me that you've content where parts of that content still need to be escaped and other parts that do not. This looks like it is mixed somehow ... or that content is intended to be served as UTF-8 and the "unescaped parts" do not need to be escaped, because of the charset that is used.

Comment: Updated my answer with some hints about encoding. Maybe this helps solving your encoding issues. I would recommend that you work on solving this first since there is a good chance you do not have to care about escaping anymore when solved your encoding issues.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to store the Text HTML-Escaped in your Database? This is for presentation and does not belong in the core data of your application. Store the String in a encoding you've chosen (it certainly does not matter which, as long its consistent and can handle all the characters you need) and process the data that way. Ergo: The core of your problem isn't the database.

The issue that the copyright symbol isn't displayed correctly can have several reasons. Like you're sending the browser UTF-8 Text but the appropriate `Content-Type`claims your content is of some other encoding.

A post which covers all aspects on this topic would be quite extensive, but you can find good documentation in the web.

Nevertheless, if you insist to store HTML-Escaped data: `string.replace("\u00a9", "&copy;");`

Comment: ok.. now somethings have started working - for the most part. The problem is now with displaying the copyright character. Using FIREBUG, I see that the response that my server generates for the request does contain the Copyright character. Its just not being displayed that way; head does contain charset as utf-8!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
result = input.replace("\u00a9", "&copy;");
```

[The copyright symbol in Unicode is hex a9.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a9/index.htm)

Comment: replace("\u00a9", "&copy;") just doesn't work! I don't know why. I converted my input string to utf-8 before calling replace, just to make sure everything is in utf8. Strange part is that my browser doesn't display that copyright symbol - even the server generates and passes the response correctly ( i checked the response via firebug)

Comment: `I converted my input string to utf-8 before calling replace, just to make sure everything is in utf8. `  doesn't make sense.  Strings are not in _any_ encoding, and `replace()` is a String method.  What exactly did you do?  Also, to make sure it's the character code it should be, you might put in some debug output/log showing the numeric value of that `char` - convert it to an `int` and output it.